# page speed metrics on javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to know how long does my page loads for my clients. Need to know when people start see all the visual elements.

Got and Idea to get use this on top of my page:

```
var time = new Date();
```

And use the time on the window.onload event and use the difference between them like the time that page loads.

Is this approach right or there is a more cleverer approach?
Maybe should use an onload event from the last element on page?

Would be great if you know a ready to use script to get the page load time in ms.